# Passing ViewData value from controller to view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making an ajax call to my controller method and expecting a result back to my view. However, my view is not displaying the value coming from the controller method even through the controller is returning the `ViewData` value.

Scanner View (Stripped version for brevity)

```
<div class="card card-outline-danger card-danger">
    <div class="card-block">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
            <p>Result In</p>
            <div id="resultsList"></div>
            <p>Result Out</p>
            @ViewData["TextAreaResult"]
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home Controller

```
public IActionResult Scanner() {
    ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = "No Scan yet";
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DecodeScanner(string productCode, string serialNumber, string batch, string expirationDate, int commandStatusCode) {
    try {
        Control.Initialize();
        Control control = new Control();
        Request request = new Request();

        request.setProductCode(productCode);
        request.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
        request.setBatch(batch);
        request.setExpirationDate(expirationDate);
        request.setCommandStatusCode(commandStatusCode);

        control.sendSinglePackOperation(request);

        Console.WriteLine("Response:" + request.getHttpResponseCode());

        ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = string.Format(" Response {0}", request.getHttpInformation());

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = "Exception: " + exc.Message;
    }

    return View("Scanner");
}
```

JS (Stripped version for brevity)

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DecodeScanner",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            productCode: productCode,
            serialNumber: serialNumber,
            batch: batch,
            expirationDate: expirationDate,
            commandStatusCode: 0
        },
        async: true
    });
});
```

In the response section under network tab, I can see the result is being passed by the controller after the successful ajax call, but the updated value of `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` is not rendered in the view. I guess it is somehow related to the new value is not passed due to no page refresh.

The output I am expecting (in this case) is to display `Response The pack is active`

Network tab - Ajax call response
[image]

HTML view - Still shows the default `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` text defined in `Scanner()` function.
[image]

Comment: The other details get updated in the view?

Comment: You try: Html.Raw(ViewData["HTMLData"].ToString())

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by other details. I am only passing the TextAreaResult string from the controller which is not getting updated. Rest of the details on the page is coming from JS code. The only problem is the result out section where I am expecting the TextAreaResult value

Comment: `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` is in Scanner view or DecodeScanner View?

Comment: I think to change `ViewData` value you need to trigger postback instead of AJAX callback. `$.ajax` often used to return partial view instead of entire view.

Comment: @zaq Other data in the view is getting updated? You need replace the html to that returned from the DecodeScanner action.

Comment: @Manoj I see your point now. The initial rendering is occurring when `Scanner()` is called and the `http` request is made in `DecodeScanner`. How do I updated the `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` coming from `DecodeScanner `  in `Scanner` view

Comment: @User3250 How do I update the `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` from DecodeScanner action to Scanner view?

Comment: @zaq , try it using without `ajax call` because it always comes back to its success or error response and that's why viewbag losts its value.

Comment: @TejinderSingh How do I pass the values to the controller withoutthe ajax call?

Comment: try using `html.beginForm`  or `form.submit()`

Comment: There is no form on the page. The values are being decoded on the fly using a handheld barcode decoder and my JS function is passing the values to the ajax method

Comment: but ajax request will clear the viewdata, share your html code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150943/discussion-between-tejinder-singh-and-zaq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` which is already rendered. you need to do this for achieving this

**Scanner View**

Put viewdata in p tag

```
  <p id="pTextAreaResult">@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]</p>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DecodeScanner(string productCode, string serialNumber, string batch, string expirationDate, int commandStatusCode) {
    string TextAreaResult = string.Empty;
    try {
        Control.Initialize();
        Control control = new Control();
        Request request = new Request();

        request.setProductCode(productCode);
        request.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
        request.setBatch(batch);
        request.setExpirationDate(expirationDate);
        request.setCommandStatusCode(commandStatusCode);

        control.sendSinglePackOperation(request);

        Console.WriteLine("Response:" + request.getHttpResponseCode());

        TextAreaResult = string.Format(" Response {0}", request.getHttpInformation());

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        TextAreaResult = "Exception: " + exc.Message;
    }

    return Json(TextAreaResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Script**

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DecodeScanner",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            productCode: productCode,
            serialNumber: serialNumber,
            batch: batch,
            expirationDate: expirationDate,
            commandStatusCode: 0
        },
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
           $('#pTextAreaResult').text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't have a `DecodeScanner ` view. Actually, DecodeScanner is just an action which does the processing and return the data into `Scanner` view

Comment: Show your ajax response method

Comment: That's all the code I have which I have posted in the question.

Comment: Can I somehow use only `Scanner()` action and do the `[HttpPost]` call from the ajax method?

Comment: Wait I am updating mt asnwer

Comment: Getting the following 2 build errors: 1) Non-invocable member 'string.Empty' cannot be used like a method. 2) The name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I think `JsonRequestBehavior` has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: Just remove `()` from ` string.Empty()` this looks like ` string.Empty` I just forgot about it. And you are working in mvc. So System.Web.Mvc have JsonRequestBehavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150939/discussion-between-manoj-and-zaq).

Comment: In asp.net core simply use this `return Json(TextAreaResult);`

Comment: The return statement `return Json(TextAreaResult);` only returns the string `"Response " ` not `request.getHttpInformation()` along with it.

Comment: Try debugging request.getHttpInformation() is empty so it's only `"Response "`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere in your code where you actually update the View with the returned HTML?

If you add a success callback to your AJAX post, you could do something like this:

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DecodeScanner",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            productCode: productCode,
            serialNumber: serialNumber,
            batch: batch,
            expirationDate: expirationDate,
            commandStatusCode: 0
        },
        async: true            
    }).done(function(html) {
        $('.card').replaceWith(html);
    });
});
```

(Not tested but hopefully you get the idea)

Comment: Wouldn't it just render the whole html page within `.card` div? How should I only extract the `@ViewData["TextAreaResult"]` part and replace it in the view?

Comment: Because you were using an AJAX call to refresh the page I've assumed that your view is only a partial view... is that not the case?